# How can I use a comparison function with more than 2 arguments with a c++ priority queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have an object class that stores a database record.  There is also a comparison class that can take in two of these records and an additional object that describes how the ordering should be done.  I need to use these two classes with a priority queue to merge the records.  From what I can tell, I can only give a comparison function that takes 2 arguments to the priority_queue.  What is the best way to go about using this 3 argument comparator with the priority queue?

```
    priority_queue <Record, vector<Record>, Comparison(RecordA, RecordB, SortOrderObject)> pq;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a function object containing the extra information, either using `boost::bind`, `std::bind`, or by hand, then pass that object into the priority queue.  Here's a by-hand version:

```
class my_compare {
  SortOrder so;
  public:
  my_compare(const SortOrder& so): so(so) {}
  bool operator()(const Record& a, const Record& b) const {
    return comparison(a, b, so);
  }
};
```

Then pass `my_compare` as the template argument to `priority_queue`, and pass `my_compare(sort_order)` as the comparator in the queue's constructor.

Comment: The question talks about a function, but i always found more pleasant to code, if the comparation are in the class.

Comment: Don't you need to define operator< instead of operator() ?

Comment: @Gareve: It is also faster to use an object, since you don't have a call through a function pointer like if you passed in a function directly.

Comment: @DasBoot: No -- the comparator is a function object.  If you have `my_compare c`, you compare `a` and `b` using `c(a, b)`.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Is there really a difference in the performance? In one case you are passing a function pointer, in the other case the object is doing a function call. The object inherently has a pointer to it's functions, so... what's the difference?

Comment: The object's function definition is encoded into its type (i.e., the call is to a known, named function, not a function pointer), allowing for the call to be inlined and things like that.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Can you explain what's going on on this line?  "my_compare(const SortOrder& so): so(so) {}"

Comment: That's the constructor; it's just like if I had written it as `my_compare(const SortOrder& the_sort_order) {so = the_sort_order;}` except that it doesn't require default construction or an assignment operator for `SortOrder`.  Using the same name for the parameter and member variable is an idiom and "odd feature" of C++; parameters shadow member names, except in the names in the initializer list (outside the parentheses), which are always members or base classes.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Can you show me what the line to construct the priority queue should look like?  I keep getting an error telling me my SortOrder cannot appear in a constant expression.  I've tried every way I can think of.  Currently it looks like this, "priority_queue <Record, vector<Record>, my_compare(so)> pq;"

Comment: @James: `priority_queue<Record, vector<Record>, my_compare> pq(my_compare(so));`

Answer (score 1):

One way would to make the Comparison a template that takes the SortOrderObject as a parameter.